# Force gsl::as_span to return a gsl::span<const T>?

Tags: c++, templates, guideline-support-library

Given the following function, taking: a **read-only** float span (of either dynamic or any static size):

```
template <long N> void foobar(gsl::span<const float, N> x);
```

Let's say I have a `vector<float>`. Passing that as an argument doesn't work, but neither does using `gsl::as_span`:

```
std::vector<float> v = {1, 2, 3};
foobar(gsl::as_span(v));
```

The above does not compile. Apparently `gsl::as_span()` returns a `gsl::span<float>`. Besides not understanding why implicit cast to `gsl::span<const float>` isn't possible, is there a way to force `gsl::as_span()` to return a read-only span?

Comment: Would changing `foobar` to `foobar(const gsl::span<float, N> & x)` work for you?

Comment: It would probably compile, but I thought the GSL advised to use span<const T> for read-only spans? A const span of non-const elements differs from a non-const span of const elements. I want the interface to say: the elements _inside_ the span are immutable.

Comment: I don't know the GSL library, and I do appreciate there's a difference between the two types.  I didn't know if that difference was important to you or not.

Comment: Ah, no problem. Wasn't sure if you did (more info on the GSL can be found at https://github.com/microsoft/gsl). But yes, the difference is important for this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poking around GSL/span.h on the github page you linked to, I found the following overload of `as_span` that I believe is the one being called here:

```
template <typename Cont>
constexpr auto as_span(Cont& arr) -> std::enable_if_t<
    !details::is_span<std::decay_t<Cont>>::value,
    span<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arr.size(), *arr.data())>, dynamic_range>>
{
    Expects(arr.size() < PTRDIFF_MAX);
    return {arr.data(), narrow_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(arr.size())};
}
```

There's lots to digest here, but in particular the return type of this function boils down to `span<std::remove_reference<decltype(*arr.data())>, ...>`.  For your given `vector<float>` gives `span<float,...>` because `decltype(*arr.data())` is `float &`.  I believe the following should work:

```
 const auto & cv = v;
 foobar(as_span(cv));
```

but can't test it myself unfortunately.  Let me know if this works.

Comment: Yeap, that works! In actuality my `foobar` might take two or three of those spans, so it's a bit of a cumbersome workaround, but hey, it does the trick!

Comment: You could always make your own function `as_cspan` that does this for you.

Comment: Just did, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`as_span` is not part of MS/GSL any more, probably because `gsl::span` was lately aligned to `std::span` - which you could now use with C++20.

You can use `std::as_const` to get a const container and create a `gsl::span` from that (or in your case to use `gsl::as_span` on it).

```
foobar(gsl::span<const float>(std::as_const(v)));
```

Please note that depending on the implementation of `foobar` it is not necessary to template it. You could also just write

```
void foobar(gsl::span<const float> x);
```

Per default the length of the span is `dynamic_extent`, so spans of any length would be accepted. Of course you would not have the length available during compile time.